# Average values of a group of turtles

Tags: netlogo

The deal is this:
I have three types of turtles. 
Every type of turtles contain three turtles
Each turtle has three variable with its own value
How could i ask netlogo to get the average value of each group of turtles

Comment: Can you post your existing code?

Comment: The thing is that I don't know how to type the code.                            The closer code is this 
"Ask TT [ SHOW (comunicación) + (combustible) + (prevención) + (atención)]"
But I can not get what I want.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean something like

```
let type1-average-x mean [x] of turtles with [type = "1"]
```

You'll want to do this for each type and for each variable that you'd like the measure of.